# "Please upgrade your dependency to build_web_compilers: ">=2.0.0", but it already is

Tags: angular-dart, dart-pub

I have an AngularDart-based web project. When I'm try `webdev serve`, I get this:

```
[SEVERE] Support for dartdevc in build_web_compilers < 2.0.0 has been removed.

Please upgrade your dependency to:

dev_dependencies:
  build_web_compilers: ">=2.0.0"

[SEVERE] Exception: dartdevc is no longer supported by this version
```

However, I already have the dependency set to "2.0.0 and newer". Here is my `pubspec.yaml` file:

```
name: myproject
description: My Description

environment:
  sdk: '>=2.3.3 <3.0.0'

dependencies:
  angular: ^5.2.0
  angular_components: ^0.13.0

dev_dependencies:
  angular_test: ^2.2.0
  build_runner: ^1.5.0
  build_test: ^0.10.3
  build_web_compilers: ^2.0.0
  pedantic: ^1.0.0
  test: ^1.5.1
```

I tried `pub get`, `pub upgrade`, `pub activate global webdev`, even `pub cache repair`.
In general, I seem to have problems with dependencies when creating AngularDart projects, even when I use versions from [the Dart docs](https://dart.dev/tools/webdev#depending-on-build_-packages). Is there a magic way to know exactly which version numbers to use?

Comment: Can you try to remove node_modules and try to install again?

Comment: @deen - stupid question: How do I do that? node_modules is not mentioned in the pubspec, and I don't see it referenced in "pub deps", and there's no directory with that name.

Comment: My bad, I've worked on Angular and many times I've faced dependency issues so I try to remove node_modules and re-install it again. I'm not sure if AngularDart having node_modules or not. Apologize for question.

Comment: I think he is suggesting removing .dart_tool directory .. node_modules is a node.js thing .. but his heart is in the right place .. .dart_tool is where your dependencies are storied and compilation artifacts .. whenever dart/webdev is doing something weird always good practice to delete it and do pub get and webdev serve again

Comment: YES! That was it! Thank you @BrianGorman and deen. If either of you want to write a proper answer, go ahead and claim your 25 points. Otherwise I'm going to write an answer in a few days.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try deleting your `.dart_tool` directory, rerun `pub get` and try again.

That directory is where dart stores all of the dependencies and artifacts of the build process.  Sometimes it can get in an odd state.

Whenever your Dart build is misbehaving in ways that defy explanation, it is good practice to delete the `.dart_tool` directory first and build clean to see if that fixes it.